# paypal express checkout=>find total item ordered

Tags: paypal

How to find the total number of items order through express check out. I am getting all other things but unable to get total items ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the GetTransactionDetails API Call send this:

```
L_QTYn
```

From the PayPal Documentation this is Quantity set by you or entered by the buyer.
Character length and limitations: no limit

If you need additional details of the different fields for GetTransactionDetails API Call, here is the direct link to the PayPal Developer Site:

[PayPal Developer GetTransactionDetails Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP)

Comment: Thanks for the support sir, actually L_QTYn count the quantity of particular items only but it doesn't show the total number of items order. https://gist.github.com/steve-todorov/3671626 , i goes through this link and count the matching key and solve the problem. Anyway thanks for the support sir.